# django select_related Cannot resolve keyword

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to optimize my ORM queries in django. I use connection.queries to view the queries that django generate for me.

Assuming I have these models:

```
class Template_folder(models.Model):
    tf_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tf_foldername = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    tf_parent = models.IntegerField()
    tf_seq = models.IntegerField()
    tf_sorter = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'template_folder'


class Templateforein(models.Model):
    tp_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tp_idfolder = models.ForeignKey(Template_folder, to_field='tf_id', db_column='tp_idfolder')
    tp_title = models.TextField(max_length=45)
    tp_contents = models.TextField()
    tp_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    tp_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    tp_iduser = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'template'
```

So should I use:

```
template = Templateforein.objects.select_related().filter(Q(tf_id=tp_idfolder) | Q(tf_parent=tp_idfolder))
```

I have to use the template_folder model.

Error content:

```
    django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'tf_id'   
  into field. Choices are: tp_choice, tp_confolderid, tp_contents, 
   tp_created, tp_flowid, tp_id, tp_idfolder, tp_idfolder_id, tp_iduser, 
   tp_pagenum, tp_title, tp_updated
```

I think you should use the template model. I should use the template_folder model.
How do I hang a filter with template_folder?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is do a [lookup that spans a relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) e.g.

```
MyObject.objects.filter(myforeignkeyfieldname__id=id)
```